# Why is the font size of subcaptions smaller than what I defined?

Tags: fontsize, subcaption

I don't know if this complies with the specification, but I'd like the subcaption has the same size as the caption.

So I tried to define like this way:

```
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage[font=small]{subcaption}
```

While the font size of subcaption I got was smaller than caption size.

Strange still, I found that if I changed the option of subcaption from 'font=small' to 'font=normalsize', like this:

```
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage[font=normalsize]{subcaption}
```

Then I got the fontsize of subcaption was 'small'.

I know I've got what I want. But it's so weird, isn't it?

Here is my code for the sub-figure using the package caption and subcaption.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage[font=small]{subcaption}
\def\showFontSize{\csname f@size\endcsname pt}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subcaptionbox{AAAAA~\showFontSize }{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{a.JPG}}%
    \hfill
    \subcaptionbox{BBBBB~\showFontSize}{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{a.JPG}}%
    \caption{CCCCC~\showFontSize }
\end{figure}

fontsize\showFontSize

\end{document}
```

And here is the screenshot of my document.

[image]

Comment: In your example, all the three captions are typeset in 9pt. You can check by adding `\showFontSize` which is defined to be `\def\showFontSize{\csname f@size\endcsname pt}` (relying the fact that the current unit-less font size is stored in `\f@size`).

Comment: Thanks for your code. But i found the problem still exists.

Comment: I got "9, 9, 9, and 10". What's the version of your LaTeX, and all the included packages? Add `\listfiles` before `\begin{document}`, compile, and you can find version info near the end of log file.

Comment: Ah, the texlive 2020 on overleaf.com also gives "8, 8, 9, 10", so the change toke place between its texlive 2020 and the latest.

Comment: According to the doc of `subcaption`, it initially sets `font+=smaller`. Use `\usepackage[font=small,font+=larger]{subcaption}` works. Investigating why that behavior changed.

Comment: You means, i'll got "9,9,9, and 10" when overleaf.com upgrade the version of his LaTeX if insist on using my code?

Comment: I've reported to `caption`, see https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/-/issues/109.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [reply from Axel Sommerfeldt](https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/-/issues/109), author and current maintainer of `caption` package bundle,

- the behavior of latest release (CTAN 2020-10-28) is the correct one, and
- you can either upgrade or use `\usepackage[size=small]{subcaption}` to achieve the expected behavior (9pt in both subcaption and caption).

Comment: +1: Thanks for the effort including to contact the package author.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts!